# 'dispatch' is not defined

Tags: reactjs, redux

I've been debugging this program but with no clue, I followed [this](https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-build-a-todo-app-using-react-redux-and-immutable-js/) tutorial word by word trying to make a TODO app but I could not figure out why I am getting this error message.

> ./src/containers.js
>   Line 12:  'dispatch' is not defined  no-undef
>   Line 13:  'dispatch' is not defined  no-undef

components.js

```
import React from 'react'

class Todo extends React.Component {

    render() {
        const { todo } = this.props

        if (todo.isDone) {
            return <strike>{todo.text}</strike>
        } else {
            return <span>{todo.text}</span>
        }
    }
}

export default class TodoList extends React.Component {
    render() {

        const {todos, toggleTodo, addTodo } = this.props
        console.log(toggleTodo)

        return (
            <div className="todo">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Add todo"/>
                <ul className='todo__list'>
                    {todos.map(t => (
                    <li key={t.id} className='todo__item'>
                        <Todo todo={t} />
                    </li>
                    ))}
                </ul>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

containers.js

```
import * as components from './components.js'
import { addTodo, toggleTodo } from './actions.js'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {todos: state}
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        addTodo: text => dispatch(addTodo(text)),
        toggleTodo: id => dispatch(toggleTodo(id))
    }
}

const TodoList = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(components.TodoList)

export default TodoList
```

reducers.js

```
const reducer = (todos = [], action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'ADD_TODO': {
            return [...todos, {id: action.id, text: action.text, completed: false}]
        }
        case 'TOGGLE_TODO': {
            return todos.map(todo => todo.id === action.id ? {...todo, completed: !todo.completed} : todo)
        }

        default: {
            return todos
        }
    }
}

export default reducer
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { TodoList } from './containers'
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import reducer from './reducers'


const store = createStore(reducer)

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <TodoList />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById("app")
)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of state here:

```
mapDispatchToProps = (state) =>
```

Use dispatch:

```
mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) =>
```

In `containers.js`.

[DOC:](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html#implementing-container-components)

> container components can dispatch actions. In a similar fashion, you
>   can define a function called **mapDispatchToProps**() that receives the
>   **dispatch()** method and returns callback props that you want to inject
>   into the presentational component.