# React 6.4 - dispatch method inside async action function with createBrowserRouter

Tags: react-hooks, react-redux

I've got this on my routes:

```
  {
    path: "/user/login",
    element: <Login />,
    action: loginAction,
  },
```

So, I'm reaching the login action correctly when I submit the form in the login page.
The issue is, I'm trying to store some data using reducers but inside the loginAction is giving me an error when try to use the

```
async function action({ request }) {
  const formData = await request.formData();
  const dispatch = useDispatch(); <-- ERROR here
```

action as been imported as loginAction

```
import { action as loginAction } from "./pages/Login";
```

This is the error I'm getting:

Line 38:20:  React Hook "useDispatch" is called in function "action" that is neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook function. React component names must start with an uppercase letter. React Hook names must start with the word "use"  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks

Of course, if I change the "action" to "Action" it doesnt giving me any error  (after fixing the import) but it just doesnt work.

Any clue how to use useDispatch inside a action function from React 6.4?

Thanks!

Use reducers in action function.

Answer (score 0):

> React Hook "useDispatch" is called in function "action" that is neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook function

as the error says, you cannot call a hook like this, inside a simple function ! you should call `useDispatch`:

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();
```

inside your `function component` and make sure that it is called at the top level.

Comment: if I do that, then I get the error here inside the action function.

*await dispatch(SET_LOGIN.....*


Line 51:9:  'dispatch' is not defined  no-undef

Comment: this is a different error take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45953203/dispatch-is-not-defined), by the way you cannot declare useDispatch inside a function it should be declared inside a component or a hook.

Comment: Thanks, it's a bit different. I can use it inside the JSX component. I'm still not able to use that inside that action function because it's outside of the component. I think this issues starts becuase of the action functions on React version 6.4. Do you get what I mean or you still think it's possible?